# Error al generar un reporte de excel en php y msql con PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Estoy usando PHPExcel para generar reportes de Excel con PHP a partir de datos obtenidos de una base de datos MySQL.

Éste es el código que tengo y archivo muestra este error:

> **Fatal error**:  'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Reportes\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation\Functions.php**
>   on line **581**

---

```
<?php

require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require 'conexion.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, precio, existencia FROM productos";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

$fila = 2;

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("C.T")->setDescription("Reporte de Productos");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Productos");

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'NOMBRE');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'PRECIO');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'EXISTENCIA');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'TOTAL');

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $row['id']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$fila, $row['nombre']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$fila, $row['precio']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$fila, $row['existencia']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$fila, '=C'.$fila.'*D'.$fila);

    $fila++;

}

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Productos.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Comment: Hola, el error podría no encontrarse en tu código, ¿la librería te funcionaba antes de manera correcta?, de todos modos podrías probar otra versión de la librería. Otra solución podría ser eliminar la palabra `break;`en esa linea de código ( en _C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Reportes\excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation\Functions.php_ linea 581), vi que en ese archivo la palabra solo se repite una vez y no afectaría si se elimina.

Comment: Es un error de la librería PHPExcel, en el archivo `Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation\Functions.php`. Lo que veo es que PHPExcel es un proyecto abandonado en 2015 y sus autores recomiendan pasarse a PHPSpreadsheet. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer es un error de la librería, la versión 1.8.1 funciona correctamente. Te comparto la url donde la puedes descargar: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Ahora el archivo si abre Muchas GRACIAS!!